# Windows is not passing command line arguments to Python programs executed from the shell

Tags: python, windows, registry, command-line-arguments, file-association

I'm having trouble getting command line arguments passed to Python programs if I try to execute them directly as executable commands from a Windows command shell.  For example, if I have this program (test.py):

```
import sys
print "Args: %r" % sys.argv[1:]
```

And execute:

```
>test foo
Args: []
```

as compared to:

```
>python test.py foo
Args: ['foo']
```

My configuration has:

```
PATH=...;C:\python25;...
PATHEXT=...;.PY;....

>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

>ftype | grep Python
Python.CompiledFile="C:\Python25\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.File="C:\Python25\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.NoConFile="C:\Python25\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
```

Comment: However it works for me.

    C:\Documents and Settings\Quim>test foo
    Args: ['foo']
   


I situated test.py in the initial location for cmd.exe (%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% in properties).
For the rest there is nothing special in my setup: winxp, Activepython 2.6.5

Comment: Could you please use [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) and find all occurrences of `Python.File` in Your registry?

Comment: Wow what a frustrating bug :( I just reinstalled Python and it's still broken! The bug was reported at the Python issue tracker two years ago http://bugs.python.org/issue7936 but there's no fix - few of the devs use Windows.

Comment: Ran into this when I installed python 3.4 and tried to use python 2.7. Looks like the python 3.4 installer messed it up?

Comment: If the system is using `[HKCU|HKLM]\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\python.exe` or `[HKCU|HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\py_auto_file`, then it's misconfigured, and the offending keys should be deleted. Then use Explorer ("open with" or the file association settings app) to select the correct "Python" entry that uses the standard `[HKCU|HKLM]\SOFTWARE\Classes\Python.File` ProgId. Check the `shell\open\command` subkey in regedit. If Python 3 is installed, the command template should use the py launcher. If the launcher is installed for all users, the template should be `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`.

Comment: cmd's internal `assoc` and `ftype` commands only show and modify `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes`, so they require administrator access to write to the registry, and they're not the correct tools to use if Python is installed for the current user. You have to use regedit to modify per-user settings in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`, which takes precedence over `HKLM` settings. Plus the association to the ProgId should always be managed via Explorer instead of using `assoc`. Explorer stores the user's choice in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I think I solved this.  For some reason there is a SECOND place in the registry (besides that shown by the file associations stored in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python25\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

This seems to be the controlling setting on my system.  The registry setting above adds the "%*" to pass all arguments to python.exe (it was missing in my registry for some reason).

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows 7. What OS did you test this in?

Comment: My key is located here on Windows 7:

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2829634124-923609355-2255922086-1001\Software\Classes\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command

Comment: With the value:

C:\Python26\python.exe %1 %*

Comment: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is not the best place to check where given key is stored. See [where in the registry does Windows store, with which program to open certain file types?](http://superuser.com/questions/266268/)

Comment: Worked for me, remember that mckoss's answer is escaped or a .REG file if you are editing the values directly removed the escapes in there

Comment: Worked also for me under Windows 8. The Python 3.x installer did everything right at the beginning, but the problem arose when I added also the 2.x version.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that python26 install (python-2.6.amd64.msi) is setting this badly. It fixed for me at your registry location with the exact following string: "C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1" %*

Comment: Note that depending on how you run this batch script, %1 may have to be changed to %%1

Comment: On a side note: The root cause of this might be due to an initial file association with .py files prior to the Python install.  Just ran into this issue, files of type .py had been associated with Notepad and then Python was installed and this ugly problem reared its ugly head.  On Windows 10 BTW.

Comment: Recently changed the launcher to use C:\Windows\py.exe, and came across this bug.  However, I modified the key in @StevenKeith's version, with "py.exe" substituted for "python.exe"

Comment: This was absolutely my problem.  The behavior WORKED before, and somehow I did something that caused this change you mention to revert.  No idea what made the change in the first place, nor what removed it.  But THANK YOU!

Answer (score 14):

My setting was under yet another registry key, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file`. The other keys mentioned also existed, but Windows was using this one for some reason.

Answer (score 14):

For Python 3.3 on Windows 7, my setting was under another registry key; the key I changed to make the arguments get passed was

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3922133726-554333396-2662258059-1000_Classes\py_auto_file\shell\open\command`

It was `"C:\Python\Python33\python.exe" "%1"`. I only appended `%*` to it.  The key's value is now `"C:\Python\Python33\python.exe" "%1" %*`.

I had several (at least five) other keys with the value `"C:\Python\Python33\python.exe" "%1"`, but this is the one I changed that made it work.

Answer (score 5):

To make it working for me, I had to use the registry path:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
```

and added a `%*`

Answer (score 5):

Here are .reg files to fix for Python 3.6, 2.7 and Anaconda3:

**python-3.6.0.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
@="Python.File"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyc]
@="Python.CompiledFile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyw]
@="Python.NoConFile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Python36\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python36\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File]
@="Python File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Python36\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python36\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile]
@="Compiled Python File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Python36\\DLLs\\pyc.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python36\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile]
@="Python File (no console)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Python36\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python36\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

*python-2.7.0.reg*

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
@="Python.File"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyc]
@="Python.CompiledFile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyw]
@="Python.NoConFile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Python27\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File]
@="Python File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Python27\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile]
@="Compiled Python File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Python27\\DLLs\\pyc.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile]
@="Python File (no console)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Python27\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

*ananconda3.reg* (change username)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
@="Python.File"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyc]
@="Python.CompiledFile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyw]
@="Python.NoConFile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File]
@="Python File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile]
@="Compiled Python File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\DLLs\\pyc.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile]
@="Python File (no console)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\DLLs\\py.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

Answer (score 1):

If fixed this on my Windows 10 system by editing the following registry keys:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\Open\Command
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command
```

to this value:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Comment: is this a bug in the python windows installer?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of thanks for the most of other answers for helping me to find the solution!

My case was to open `.py`-files with `py.exe` (not `python.exe` directly), this case it noted in a couple of comments, but I decided to post this as a separate answer to emphasize the difference.

So I have my `.py`-files associated with `C:\Windows\py.exe` and in `C:\Windows\py.ini` config I have a couple of shebang definitions

```
[commands]
<my_venv_py> = C:\Programs\my_venv_py\Scripts\python.exe
<my_venv_py_w> = C:\Programs\my_venv_py\Scripts\pythonw.exe
```

to use in my scripts like this `#!<MY_VENV_PY>`.

And on Microsoft Windows 7 [Version 6.1.7601] my python script **did NOT** received the args like this

```
script.py 1 2
```

but this worked fine

```
py script.py 1 2
```

File associations were OK

```
> assoc .py
.py=Python.File

> ftype | grep Python
File STDIN:
Python.CompiledFile="C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*
Python.File=C:\Windows\py.exe "%L" %*
Python.NoConFile="C:\Windows\pyw.exe" "%1" %*
```

I've tried much of registry changes, but the last helped was the following change (saved to a `.reg`-file and run). I've found this registry key searching `"%1"` string with initial value `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1"` and added `%*` in the end as other answers note:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\py.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\py.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

For information, before I tried to setup these keys and values and did not helped (at least before the noted above):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
@="Python.File"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.py]
@="Python.File"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.py]
@="Python.File"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py]
@="Python.File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file]
@="Python File"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\py.exe\" \"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File]
@="Python File"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\py.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to modify this in Windows 10 to get it to work (%* at the end)

Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2364940108-955964078-1358188674-1001\Software\Classes\Applications\py.exe\shell\open\command

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Works here using python 2.6 and Windows XP (5.1.2600):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\hbrown>python test.py foo
['test.py', 'foo']

C:\Documents and Settings\hbrown>test.py foo
['C:\\Documents and Settings\\hbrown\\test.py', 'foo']

C:\Documents and Settings\hbrown>test foo
['C:\\Documents and Settings\\hbrown\\test.py', 'foo']

C:\Documents and Settings\hbrown>type test.py
import sys
print sys.argv 

C:\Documents and Settings\hbrown>echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.PY 

C:\Documents and Settings\hbrown>assoc .py
.py=Python.File
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program associations for `.py` files might be messed up. Just re-associate `.py` files with your python executable.

Right click a `.py` file > `Open with` > `Choose default program ...` > [find C:\PythonXY\python.exe]

Comment: Did not work on my system, as it always defaulted to calling Python 3.6. The [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641185/5991423) did work

Comment: There are problems since Windows10, so this does not work always.

Answer (score 0):

I checked all registry keys with `python.exe` and `py_auto_file` and made them point to my current python installation including th `%*` at the end that passes arguments. They were quite a few:

> - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command:
>
>   - org: "C:\miniconda3\python.exe" "%1" "%*"
>   - changed: "C:\Python35\python.exe" "%1" "%*"
> - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
>
>   - org: "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%1"
>   - changed: "C:\Python35\python.exe" "%1" "%*"
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
>
>   - org: "C:\Python35\python.exe" "%1" "%*"
> - HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2621213409-1291422344-4183577876-2165\Software\Classes\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
>
>   - org: "C:\Python35\python.exe" "%1" "%*"
> - HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2621213409-1291422344-4183577876-2165_Classes\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
>
>   - org: "C:\Python35\python.exe" "%1" "%*"
> - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\pythonw.exe\shell\open\command
>
>   - org: "C:\Python34\pythonw.exe" "%1"
>   - changed: "C:\Python35\pythonw.exe" "%1" "%*"
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command
>
>   - org: "C:\Python35\python.exe" "%1" "%*"

But that didn't do the job for me. I had to change my default python application as well.

[image: Application dialog]

As one can see I have 3 Python versions installed. It is impossible to see which is which here so I tried all three of them as my default python application. Eventually I was able to get my script arguments with one of these three.

Answer (score 0):

By looking through the Windows registry, I found all the places where anything like
`Python36\pythonw.exe "%1" %*` appears.

When I type `python app.py args` at the command prompt, everything works properly.

When I use just the app name (`app.py args`) Windows opens app.py in Python, but the app fails when it tries to access argv[1], because len(argv) is 1.

Apparently Windows knows enough to pass a py file to Python, but I can't figure out from looking at registry entries how it constructs the command. It appears to be using `"%1"` rather than `"%1" %*`.