# Django is not accepting arguments in Windows

Tags: python, windows, django

I have installed django on my windows vista computer and can add the django library to a python script, but cannot seem to ge teh following to work correctly from the command line:

django-admin.py startproject mysite

When I try to run this or the help command I always get the default message that shows all the commands as if I did not send it the second argument.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I figured out the issue based on another thread I found here:

[Windows is not passing command line arguments to Python programs executed from the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t)

The issue was about how the registry was handling my calls to admin.py and the fact that it was dropping the arguments I passed.

Hope this helps others who run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

you may `cd` to the dir which the `django-admin.py` in

Comment: I have tried this with no success. Using you suggestions does not change anything sadly. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest headache I've run into with developing on Windows is path issues. I use virtualenv and [David Marble's port of virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win) As such, I fully qualify the path to django-admin.py. Of course, the virtualenv's site-packages could get added to my PATH, but I find it just as easy to just paste in the path.

Try fully qualifying the path to django-admin.py and see if that gets you going.

Answer (score 0):

If python variable environment is set you should try something like

```
python Path\to\django\installation\bin\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```