# How to use randomTrips.py in SUMO on win8

Tags: sumo

I'm using randomTrips.py in SUMO to generate random trips on win8. I have a map.net.xml file and try to create a trips.xml file through randomTrips.py. However, the problem occurs and I don't know how to  deal with it. The code is as follows:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\sumo\tools>randomTrips.py -n map.net.xml -l 200 -e -o map.trips.xml

I don't get the .trips.xml file I want. And the outcome is as follows, it seems that I have missed some properties of the function in my code, but I don't know how to correct it. If anyone knows how to solve the problem, pls give me some valuable suggestions. Thanks.
The outcome is :

Usage: randomTrips.py [options]

Options:

-h, --help            show this help message and exit

-n NETFILE, --net-file=NETFILE
                        define the net file (mandatory)

-a ADDITIONAL, --additional-files=ADDITIONAL
                        define additional files to be loaded by the rout

-o TRIPFILE, --output-trip-file=TRIPFILE
                        define the output trip filename

-r ROUTEFILE, --route-file=ROUTEFILE
                        generates route file with duarouter

--weights-prefix=WEIGHTSPREFIX
                        loads probabilities for being source, destinatio
                        via-edge from the files named .src.xml,
                        .sink.xml and .via.xml

--weights-output-prefix=WEIGHTS_OUTPREFIX
                        generates weights files for visualisation

--pedestrians         create a person file with pedestrian trips inste
                        vehicle trips

--persontrips         create a person file with person trips instead o
                        vehicle trips

--persontrip.transfer.car-walk=CARWALKMODE
                        Where are mode changes from car to walking allow
                        (possible values: 'ptStops', 'allJunctions' and
                        combinations)

--persontrip.walkfactor=WALKFACTOR
                        Use FLOAT as a factor on pedestrian maximum spee
                        during intermodal routing

--prefix=TRIPPREFIX   prefix for the trip ids

-t TRIPATTRS, --trip-attributes=TRIPATTRS
                        additional trip attributes. When generating
                        pedestrians, attributes for  and 
                        supported.

--fringe-start-attributes=FRINGEATTRS
                        additional trip attributes when starting on a fr

-b BEGIN, --begin=BEGIN
                        begin time

-e END, --end=END     end time (default 3600)

-p PERIOD, --period=PERIOD
                        Generate vehicles with equidistant departure tim
                        period=FLOAT (default 1.0). If option --binomial
                        used, the expected arrival rate is set to 1/peri

-s SEED, --seed=SEED  random seed

-l, --length          weight edge probability by length

-L, --lanes           weight edge probability by number of lanes

--speed-exponent=SPEED_EXPONENT
                        weight edge probability by speed^ (defaul

--fringe-factor=FRINGE_FACTOR
                        multiply weight of fringe edges by  (defa

--fringe-threshold=FRINGE_THRESHOLD
                        only consider edges with speed above  as
                        edges (default 0)

--allow-fringe        Allow departing on edges that leave the network
                        arriving on edges that enter the network (via
                        turnarounds or as 1-edge trips

--allow-fringe.min-length=ALLOW_FRINGE_MIN_LENGTH
                        Allow departing on edges that leave the network
                        arriving on edges that enter the network, if the
                        at least the given length

--min-distance=MIN_DISTANCE
                        require start and end edges for each trip to be
                        least  m apart

--max-distance=MAX_DISTANCE
                        require start and end edges for each trip to be
                        most  m apart (default 0 which disables a
                        checks)

-i INTERMEDIATE, --intermediate=INTERMEDIATE
                        generates the given number of intermediate way p

--flows=FLOWS         generates INT flows that together output vehicle
                        the specified period

--maxtries=MAXTRIES   number of attemps for finding a trip which meets
                        distance constraints

--binomial=N          If this is set, the number of departures per sec
                        will be drawn from a binomial distribution with
                        and p=PERIOD/N where PERIOD is the argument give
                        option --period. Tnumber of attemps for finding
                        which meets the distance constraints

-c VCLASS, --vclass=VCLASS, --edge-permission=VCLASS
                        only from and to edges which permit the given ve
                        class

--vehicle-class=VEHICLE_CLASS
                        The vehicle class assigned to the generated trip
                        (adds a standard vType definition to the output

--validate            Whether to produce trip output that is already c
                        for connectivity

-v, --verbose         tell me what you are doing

Comment: Is it a typo or have you not input any end time for the simulation, i.e., after `-e`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. But I add the end time as you suggested, it still doesn't work. Do you know what the other reason may be?

Comment: could you show me a snapshot of your `cmd` when you execute this. I believe you might have various typos

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment. Here are the snapshots of my cmd. Thanks. https://imgchr.com/i/nnROYj            https://imgchr.com/i/nnRLkQ

Answer (score 1):

Probably the file name association with .py files is broken, see [Python Command Line Arguments (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880540/python-command-line-arguments-windows). Try to run the script with python explicitly:

```
python randomTrips.py -n map.net.xml -l 200 -e -o map.trips.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried last week. You can search randomTrips.py under SUMO's folder. Then you find the location of randomTrips.py, then you open the cmd and call python to execute it. You also need to specify the net.xml.

Comment: You mean I need to add the path of the net.xml into the code as well ?

Comment: Yes, the code given by Michael is correct. You just need to plug in your