# Google App Engine PHP on windows

Tags: php, windows, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get started with using Google app engine with PHP (on Windows 7) and have been trying to follow the helloworld example [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld).

Problem I am having is in starting the webserver.  Whenever I try to run it I get the error

```
dev_appserver.py: error: too few arguments
```

I'm typing the following at the command line:

```
google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=c:\php\php-cgi c:\appengine\helloworld\
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Use quotes for arguments.

```
google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path="c:\php\php-cgi" "c:\appengine\helloworld"
```

Or use slashes instead of backslashes as directory separator:

```
google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=c:/php/php-cgi c:/appengine/helloworld
```

For best results combine both methods ;)

Answer (score 2):

So I was running into this issue, and tried every permutation of paths using quotes, and switching to the directory where appengine SDK was installed etc. Finally I realized that Python was running the script but it wasn't including the command line arguments being passed in. So I had to manually call python like this:

```
c:\<python_path>\python <sdk_path>/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=c:/php/php-cgi.exe helloworld/
```

I'm not a python guy so I don't know why the command line arguments got stripped, but I've had this issue with other applications in Windows 7

Comment: Agreed, on windows 7:  C:\Python27\python "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" "c:\scripts3\freelance\gae-boilerplate"

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t/2641185#2641185) solved the issue for me.

Just to clarify it a bit, here is how the value under

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command`

should look in Windows regedit tool.

[image: Regedit: Edit String Value]

And it should be the same as the value under this path:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command`

Solution tested on environment: Python 2.7.5 on Windows 7 (Home Premium) x64.

In fact I had this problem not with PHP App Engine but with Go App Engine. However, it is apparently not App Engine, but rather a Python+Windows issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows 7 too.

Here it's my code tested:

`dev_appserver.py --php_executable=c:/php/php-cgi.exe c:/appengine/helloworld`

**Notice!** I'm inside google appengine directory.

For example if you installed the SDK in `C:`

Write first `cd google_appengine` hit enter, and then use the upper code.

Comment: I tried changing the directory to google_appengine and then running the command, but it still give the same result!

Answer (score 1):

You have to either: give full path to dev_appserver.py

or

cd into the directory where you instaled it

If You followed example to the letter You would have instaled it in C:/{username}/something directory

and the call would be then something/dev_appserver.py as stated in example in helloworld!

Hovever - the example have one error in it: the directory they are proposing is not the same they are using in example call! Thats why make sure the "sometinhg" directory is the same in call as used to instal app engine

Comment: I can't remember how I did it, but I believe I already did the full path thing! I installed the SDK at c:\ in a folder called google_appengine

Answer (score 0):

after I moved everything to c:\ to simplify the paths I ended up calling it from the dos command prompt like this

C:>\Python27\python C:/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=
C:/php/php-cgi.exe c:/google_appengine/helloworld/

And it works!

is the python command line tool the way we should be running this stuff?