# How to start Development Server for PHP on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

With reference to the [PHP Hello World](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld) example, I have a command prompt window open in Windows7 in which I have entered
 `google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=C:\php\php-cgi.exe C:\helloworld\`
What it does is, it Opens up a **dev_appserver.py** in a text editor, and in browser for `http://localhost:8080` I am getting error msg 
`The path specified with the --php_exectuable_path flag () does not exist.` Does anyone please know how to fix this. Eagerly waiting for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer

[Google App Engine PHP on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635651/google-app-engine-php-on-windows/16636114#16636114)

Try using quotes around your arguments or doing google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=C:/php/php-cgi.exe C:/helloworld/