# WinPython: can't see command line arguments

Tags: python

I am using WinPython with Python 3.3.2 under Windows 7. I like to be able to run python programs from the command prompt simply by typing the name of the program, like `program.py`. This didn't work at first, requiring me to type `python program.py` until I set the file associations under windows to associate .py files with python. Then it worked.

However, I just discovered that if I run a program by typing the program name, I can't see any of the command line arguments in sys.argv. For instance, `program.py arg1` will not show arg1 in sys.argv. All I see is the first argument, the name of the program. BUT, if I run the program by typing `python.exe program.py arg1` then I can arg1.

I need command-line args, but I don't want the extra typing because I'll be running commands many times. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows is not passing command line arguments to Python programs executed from the shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t)

Comment: Yes, Looks like it's worth trying the suggestions on that question before further comment here. Too bad that fixing it looks like deep delving into the registry. I don't think I even have the registry editor on Windows 7 home.

Comment: You have the registry editor, just open "Run" (with `Windows + R`) and type in `regedit.exe`.