# In Python: 'import sitecustomize' failed;

Tags: python, numpy

I just don't understand why my code generates the error message:

> 'import sitecustomize' failed

Here's the code:

```
from numpy import *
from pycalfem import *
from pycalfem_utils import *
def createInput():
edof=array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
            [1,2,7,8,3,4],
            [3,4,7,8,9,10],
            [7,8,11,12,9,10]])
dof=array([[1,2],
          [5,6],
          [7,8],
          [3,4],
          [11,12],
          [9,10]])
Coord=array([[0,0],
             [0,0.1],
             [0.1,0],
             [0.1,0.1],
             [0.2,0],
             [0.2,0.1]])
bc=array([[1,0],[2,0],[4,0],[5,0]])
ex,ey=coordxtr(edof,Coord,dof)
return ex,ey,bc,edof

if __name__=="main":
print("Hej")
ex,ey,bc,edof=createInput()
```

Comment: Notice that your indentation in the main block is messed up, if that's what it actually looks like.

Comment: `from module import *` is a bad way of importing modules as it pollutes your namespace. Rather import the entire module or just the class / functions you need

Comment: agree with @letsc - better to do something like `import numpy as np` if you want to shorten

Comment: Ok, so rather "import numpy" than "from numpy import * " ? Also, if i comment all the code so theres nothing written, spyder still gives me the same error message. And I just tried the "import numpy" version and it didnt help.

Comment: Can you give the full error message?

Comment: sure! 'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
>>>

Comment: Is the error something along these lines? https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=771 (On second look it appears that this message comes up with a lot of errors. I would suggest you do as it says and use `-v` for a traceback then add the traceback to your question.)

Comment: Ok, so I configured my module to "execute in an external system terminal" instead of, as before, "execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter" and now it runs if i change to (if __name__ !="main"), How can i run it if its (if __name__=="main") instead?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
python -v
```

which will tell you why sitecustomize failed to import.

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as a full on answer. (It feels more comment-like.)

Comment: Im such a noob on python.. So back to basics, im using winPython and running it with Spyder. So where do I type in python -v ?

Comment: @Sam .. it looks like you'll need to hack the registry to add an argument http://stackoverflow.com/a/2641185/4275865