# Why does argparse fail to recognise an argument when a Python script is called directly?

Tags: windows, python-3.4, argparse

I have a simple script like this (based on [the docs for `argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)):

```
def Main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("issuenumber", help="Create a local branch based on the specified issue number", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.issuenumber:
        print("Starting work on issue #"+str(args.issuenumber))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

When I run it however, it never recognises the argument I'm passing it:

```
C:\Projects\PyTools>Gritter.py 1
usage: Gritter.py [-h] issuenumber
Gritter.py: error: the following arguments are required: issuenumber
```

If I call the script via a python call it works however:

```
C:\Projects\PyTools>python Gritter.py 1
Starting work on issue #1
```

If I print out `sys.argv` I get:

```
C:\Projects\PyTools>Gritter 1
['C:\\Projects\\PyTools\\Gritter.py']

C:\Projects\PyTools>Python Gritter.py 1
['Gritter.py', '1']
```

So I guess something is not passing on the arguments when the script is called directly. I wonder if there's anything that can be done so that the script can be called directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546331/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-path-independent-python-script-using-w

Comment: Which itself looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t

Answer (score 1):

The `C\` indicates you are using Windows.  You have take extra effort to ensure that this 'direct call' passes arguments through to `python`.

Looking up `windows shebang` I find, from Python docs that you need to use

```
#!/usr/bin/python -v
```

to pass arguments

See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

`argparse` uses `sys.argv`.  If that only has the script name then the call isn't passing arguments.

Comment: I tried adding `#! /usr/bin/python` but that doesn't appear to help the situation. I've also added a print-out of the args which shows calling the script directly appears to remove the extra arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [mckoss` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641185/15369), I modified the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command
```

From this:

```
"C:\Python34\python.exe" "%1"
```

To this:

```
"C:\Python34\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

And now my script works as I'd previously expected.