# How to pass parameters to an .sh script under Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, command-line, parameter-passing

I'm trying to execute .sh scripts under Windows. I installed Git, which allowed me to execute .sh files. However, I can't seem to pass any parameters around without prefixing the execution with "sh":

My .sh file:

```
echo "Test" $1
```

if I execute it with:

```
> sh test.sh 123
```

I get

> Test 123

However, if I just execute it as

```
> test.sh 123
```

I get

> Test

I know it is possible to execute .sh scripts with parameters and without prefixing them with "sh", since through some combination of configurations I was able to do it on my old computer somehow. Any guesses as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: The file association is probably incomplete.  You can view and edit file associations with the `ftype` and `assoc` commands.  `ftype /?` for help.

Comment: @HarryJohnston from assoc I see `.sh=sh_auto_file` and from ftype - `sh_auto_file="C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --no-cd "%L" %*` . What should it be instead and how do I change it?

Comment: Try adding `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the first line of the `sh` file.

Comment: Well, the association already passes the arguments along, so that looks OK.  It is running `git-bash.exe` rather than `sh` but I guess those are synonyms?  What does `git-bash test.sh 123` do?

Comment: It prints `Test 123`. My other computer's configuration is `sh_auto_file="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" "--login" "%1" %*` . By the way, how do I change the ftype configuration?

Comment: Using the `ftype` command as per the help, e.g., `ftype sh_auto_file=git-bash "%1" %*`

Comment: @HarryJohnston Using the ftype command apparently didn't solve the issue. Turns out there were 2 or 3 places in registry that had to be switched manually - a lot of them either didn't have the %1 %* at the end and some were referencing some wrong .exe file... At least everything is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @HarryJohnston in the comments, the first step to solving this problem was figuring out the `assoc` and `ftype` associations. `assoc` will most likely return `.sh=sh_auto_file`, while in my case, `ftype` returned `sh_auto_file="C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --no-cd "%L" %*`. One part of the issue was similar to what was happening [in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t) - Windows was not passing parameters to the .sh file. To fix that, the `sh_auto_file` association needs to end with / have `"%1" %*` as a part of it apparently. However, another part of the problem was that (at least on Windows 10 in my case), there might be multiple places in the registry that have a wrong record. In the end I had to manually change 2-3 entries in registry to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" "%1" %*` in order for it to finally work. To find those places, search for `.sh` and `sh_auto_file` and replace accordingly.

Bonus: To make .sh files execute without having to write ".sh" at the end, add .SH to `pathext` in environmental variables.