# How to make ConEmu execute .sh in the same window with Git for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, sh, conemu

I'm using ConEmu on Windows with Git for Windows installed. When I try to execute an .sh script, the software starts an instance of Windows' default console and executes the script there. How can I make ConEmu / Git for Windows execute the .sh script in the same window the command is initialized from?

Comment: You have not described how exactly you are trying to run the script!

Comment: You also posted this on [su]. Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: @Maximus I just type the script's filename into ConEmu and it runs when I press enter. I'm assuming it's handled automatically by Git for Windows.

Comment: We still do not know what shell do you use and hire do you start it in ConEmu.

Comment: @Maximus How would I figure out which shell I use?

Comment: Don't you know what you are working with? Look at ConEmu settings: Startup. Look at ConEmu status bar at last.

Comment: @Maximus Here are my ConEmu startup settings - https://imgur.com/bdtgaRn . CMD shell?

Comment: run `bash yourscript.sh` to reuse console

Comment: @Maximus
> bash all.sh

'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Maximus Okay, it looks like my Git/bin wasn't included in PATH. I'll have to try doing that and see if it fixes my issue.

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/a/454381/78786

Answer (score 4):

So there are a few things one needs to do after a clean install of ConEmu and Git for Windows to make everything run seamlessly.

1) `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` needs to be added to PATH. Git for Windows only appears to add `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`to PATH. This should allow you to run commands like `sh test.sh ABC` and they should work

2) To make things even easier and not have to type `sh` all the time, we need to tell Windows to associate .sh with sh, as well as [pass parameters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107863/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-sh-script-under-windows). We do this by typing:

`assoc .sh=sh`

`ftype sh="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" "%1" %*`

3) If parameters are still not passed, it might be a registry issue. To fix it, we press Win+r, type in `regedit` and run the Registry Editor. There might be a few places where the edit needs to be made, but one of them should be `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\sh.exe\shell\open\command`. We edit the entry to say

`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" "%1" %*`

4) Bonus: To make .sh files execute without having to write ".sh" at the end, add .SH to `PATHEXT` in environmental variables.

That should allow us to run .sh files from ConEmu using Git for Windows without it opening in a separate window.

Comment: One note. Adding `git/bin` or `git/usr/bin` may break .cmd scripts, if the directory contains such files as `find.exe`. So, it's preferable to modify `PATH` in the ConEmu task command.