# Execution of Python script with parameter and Windows10 doesn't work

Tags: python, windows-10

I've got some Python scripts, which I used from cmd line or batch files or with drag&drop to do useful things.

Example:

```
makeMyWork.py "hi" 77
```

Now I got Win10 :-(

Windows10 doesn't forward the **parameters** to my python scripts. I have to write:

```
c:\Python27\python.exe makeMyWork.py "hi" 77
```

A lot of automatism isn't working anymore now. I started to change some important batch-files, but that's a lot of work. I want have back, the old behavior.

What can I do now ?

Comment: We cannot help you unless you post what is inside `makeMyWork.py`

Comment: Windows is not linux. Put the python location in your `$PATH$` environment variable and you'll only have to type "`python makeMyWork.py`"

Comment: It was working with WinXp,7,8 without extending `$PATH$`.

Comment: @Jason: Please read my question first. It's about the command line params are not passed to the python script. It's not about the content of the python script.

Comment: @Goodies: I've no problems of executing a script with python.exe. It's about the paramaters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, after searching with *Google* instead of *hulbee*, I found the answer:

[Windows is not passing command line arguments to Python programs executed from the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t)

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command]
>   @="\"C:\Python25\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"

Thanks to **mckoss**

To make it working for me, I'd to use the registry path:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command
```

and added a `%*` to the parameter

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Right click on a python script and use open-with to open with your python.exe

Step 2: Change registry so that running your python script from command line will cause python.exe to read individual arguments, and not to combine all arguments into a single string.

Note that due to Windows limits, only the first 8 arguments are available individually.  Downside is os.argv will contains empty strings appended when less than 8 arguments.  The alternative is to use %* which would join all arguments with spaces but make it available as sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAtr3.png)

The fix is to add a code:
while sys.argv[-1] == '':
del sys.argv[-1]

Use Regedit, or save below to a .reg file, edit the path, then run it.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command]
@=""C:\Users\andrewm\anaconda3\python.exe" "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4" "%5" "%6" "%7" "%8" "

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@=""C:\Users\andrewm\anaconda3\python.exe" "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4" "%5" "%6" "%7" "%8" "

[regedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAtr3.png)

Comment: instead of :
     "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4" "%5" "%6" "%7" "%8" 
it's simpler, and uses all available params:
    " \"%1\" %*"