# 2to3 Not Working at all

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently downloaded the deuces module from GitHub, and want to convert it into python 3. I put the 2to3 script into my path and navigated to the directory of the module. I used the command `2to3.py card.py` and it returns the error:

```
At least one file or directory argument required.
Use --help to show usage.
```

I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you type `2to3.py --help`, does it show how to use the program or does it show the same error?

Comment: @VincentSavard It shows the same eror

Comment: I assume you use Windows? You probably didn't configure passing parameters to the script when executing a Python file directly from the command line. Try `python 2to3.py card.py` instead.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: You can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t) to fix the initial issue.