# Command-line arguments dropped when running python file directly on Windows

Tags: python, windows, command-line-arguments

I'm learning to include command line parameters in my code. I've read the docs for `argparse` and I tried running this script from there.

```
#argparse_trial.py

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                const=sum, default=max,
                help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

If I run

```
>python argparse_trial.py 1
```

in the command line, I get the expected result `1`
But if I run

```
>argparse_trial.py 1
```

I get

```
usage: arg_parse_trial.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]
argparse_trial.py: error: the following arguments are required: N
```

I checked and the only argument the code seems to receive in the second case is the filename itself, no matter how many arguments are given.
I'm on a Windows machine and python is in my path.

Why is the second case failing in this script? How can I get it to work?

Comment: I don't know how to phrase this question properly, so feel free to make it better

Comment: I'm not sure how you are able to execute a python script without the python executable. At least on Windows.

Comment: Like I said, python is in my path

Comment: But you're not typing its name, so the system will not look for it.

Comment: Well, how come the file is executed then? I run all my .py files without adding python before them and they've all worked properly till now

Comment: it's working fine in my system. http://imgur.com/dqzvIjz

Comment: At least on linux, you have a shebang at the top of the file and you mark it as executable... I didn't realize Windows would work the same

Comment: @Bhansa Do you think I doing something else wrong? Some basic windows thing?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t). Can somebody mark it one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess, I cannot test right now, but I believe this is what is happening:

1. you type the name of your python file.
2. Windows fails to run the file as a program, so…
3. Windows tries to open the file, using the associated program (kindof with using `start`).
4. While doing so, it simply ignores other things on the line, and…
5. …generates a basic command line for the python
   interpreter to use, featuring just the interpreter itself and the
   target file to open.

Think of what happens when you "run" a text document.

If the command line is not generated correctly, running this command should fix it (replace the path as appropriate):

```
ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Notice the `%*` at the end. If it's amiss, arguments will be dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I run `youtube-dl` on a regular basis. I've never included python before it and it accepts a lot of command-line arguments

Comment: `youtube-dl` is a regular executable (`youtube-dl.exe`), it will not follow this process.

Comment: what about `virtualenv` ? how does that work.

Comment: No. I don't have the executable. I installed it with pip. Its a .py file. I'm going through its code right now to see if I can understand anything but it looks very complicated for my level.

Comment: Can you check you python file association then? It should look like `D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe "%1" %*`. If the `%*` is missing, it could cause arguments to be dropped.

Comment: @Bhansa Can you elaborate?

Comment: @spectras What do mean python file association?

Comment: @GughanRavikumar> the [settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-file-open-program) that tell windows how to open a `.py` file.

Comment: @spectras yes, that's correct. I actually tried to set the default program as sublime and it just opened the file the editor when i typed the `program name.py` in command line.

Comment: @spectras That seems to be the problem. Mine is set to `python.exe`.  How do I change it to `python.exe "1" %*`?  I can only choose `.exe` files. I can't add the `"1" %*` anywhere

Comment: I don't have a windows box, but I suppose there should be an option to edit the command manually. I just found this relevant question: http://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7

Comment: @GughanRavikumar> can you run `assoc | more` and find out the name used for python files? If so, it's possible to set the association from the command line with that information.

Comment: @spectras thank you. That solved my problem

Comment: @spectras @Bhansa My problem is solved, but just to know.. Can you think of a reason why `youtube-dl` worked properly even before I did this?

Comment: yes, because these are all exe files and will work if you have path provided in the environment variable.

Comment: @Bhansa I do not have the .exe version. I installed it using pip. It is a .py file.

Comment: check C:/Python27/Scripts and see.

Comment: @Bhansa My bad, then. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @GughanRavikumar Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

I think the code is working fine. You can execute the program by just choosing the default program to be `python.exe` for python files.

 In your case `python.exe "1" %*` as @spectras suggested, so it will be able take command line arguments.

Also provide the path environment variable.
Programs like `pip,virtualenv and youtube-dl` are all executable files and if have already set the environment variable, we use it anywhere.

How to choose default program on windows:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7

Comment: My default program is `python.exe`. It has to be `python.exe "1" %*`, thanks to @spectra. Just change that, I'll make yours the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can Use sys library included in python and use argv() function to perform various command argunment.

find this video tutorial intuitive to understand how to!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLG7Tz6db0w

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to spectras' and Bhansa's answer.
For Windows 10 user's, setting advanced file associations is a bit complicated. You'll have to edit your registry files. 
Run `regedit`.
Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\py_auto_file\shell\open\command` and change the value of `Data` from
`"C:\Path\To\Python\python.exe" "1"`
to
`"C:\Path\To\Python\python.exe" "1" %*`

This might be applicable to previous versions of Windows also.

Comment: The configuration is FUBAR'd if .py files are using the automatically generated `py_auto_file` ProgId. Make sure that .py files are associated with `Python.File`. I would delete the `py_auto_file` entry and use Explorer's "open with" or the settings app to select the correct "Python" ProgId.  If the command-line template is wrong, use regedit to modify `Python.File` in the user's `HKCU` (for an all-users installation, you can use cmd's `assoc` and `ftype` to modify the `HKLM` values). If Python 3 is installed, use the fully qualified path to the "py.exe" laucher (try `where py.exe` in cmd).

Comment: @eryksun I'm sorry, I didn't understand most of what you said. I've explained what I did to get it working on my system. Using explorer's `open with` you can't set advanced options, like `%*` So I had to edit the registry to get it working