# Directly calling associated script with arguments

Tags: python, windows

In Windows console if I execute this script (`test.py`):

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

like:

```
>python test.py my args
```

I get expected output:

```
['test.py', 'my', 'args']
```

but if I call it directly, like this:

```
>test.py my args
```

I get: `['C:\\temp\\test.py']` output, as if I didn't pass any arguments. Why?

FYI:

```
>assoc | findstr .py=
.py=Python.File

>ftype Python.File
Python.File=C:\Python35\python.exe "%1" %*
```

Comment: See this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t

Comment: cmd's `assoc` and `ftype` show the system definitions from `HKLM\Software\Classes`, not per-user settings from `HKCU\Software\Classes` and not the defaults defined in either `Classes` key for  `SystemFileAssociations` and `Applications`. They also don't show the *user's choice* among these settings, which is stored in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`. The user's choice is what `ShellExecuteEx` actually uses. Configure this in Explorer, with the "open with" dialog (choose another / always use) or the control panel "Default Programs".

Comment: Also, `Python.File` for a standard 3.5 installation should use the py launcher, which handles Unix-style shebangs for scripts that require other versions of Python. If the launcher is installed for all users, it's in the `%SystemRoot%` directory (e.g. "C:\Windows"), for which the command template would be `C:\Windows\py.exe "%1" %*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t), you want to make sure the `command` key is set properly. On my copies of Windows 10, I found I had the `command` reg set to `"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*` in 2 places

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.CompiledFile\shell\open\command
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command
```

I guess the first thing to do would be to check these 2 keys.