# No arguments in sys.argv when calling Python Script directly on Windows

Tags: python

I have some convenience python scripts in my path that I want to run by calling  them directly, e.g. `myscript.py argument1`. But the arguments won't show up in `sys.argv`.

**test.py**

```
#!python3.5

import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

So when I call this little script directly I can not access the given argument via `sys.argv`.

```
c:\Users\MrLeeh\bin>test.py hello
['C:\\Users\\MrLeeh\\bin\\test.py']
```

While when I call it explicitly with the `python` command I can access my argument.

```
c:\Users\MrLeeh\bin>python test.py hello
['C:\\Users\\MrLeeh\\bin\\test.py', 'hello']
```

I ask myself what is the reason for this and how can I access the arguments when using a direct call. My python files are associated with `py.exe`.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you have missed some registry configuration.

There is a registry saved in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

The registry setting above adds the "%*" to pass all arguments to python.exe

- via [mckoss's answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641185/7285157)